Why does bc not have easy to use built in support for rounding?
I just wrote a small bash shell script and for the first time in that context I wanted to make a calculation, a division, and discovered bc.
My script processes media files and I want to log the performance, that is, the length of the file divided by the duration of the processing. Typical values for the quotient is 0,03-0,05 but bc doesn't round, it truncates! Which is a problem because the difference between 0,0300 and 0,0399 is quite significant but bc will return 0,03 for both.
I have read multiple questions about making bc round, with mostly quite convoluted solutions. This made me wonder:
Why doesn't bc have native support for rounding??
I am not looking for a solution but am curious about the design decisions behind the lack of support for rounding. I am aware of the KISS philosophy but rounding floating point values is such a basic feature for any calculator.
Of course you could display the result with two more digits and the make the rounding manually (in your head), but it is weird to waste human mental energy a task that a computer is much better on performing than a human! Hence my question.

When bc was designed 40-50 years ago, "rounding" typically meant rounding to the nearest integer, not to a specific number of decimal digits.

If you only have truncating, you can implement rounding by simply adding half the value at that number of digits and then truncating, e.g.round(0.036, 2) == truncate(0.036+0.005, 2)

@Barmar  For negative numbers, you need to subtract half the value at that number of digits, as the general rule is "round away from zero". The Bash built-in like printf '%.2f\n' 2.1649 2.1751 -2.1849 -2.1951 rounds correctly, but will not do any decimal arithmetic on the args. This is where I reach for awk.

@Paul_Pedant I realize it's over-simplistic, it also doesn't implement "banker's rounding", which rounds exactly halfway to even.

@Barmar Really? I think I learned the rounding rules in school when I was about 10, and that included numbers with decimals.

@d-b I meant in computer software. I don't recall seeing a built-in round() function where you could specify the number of digits until I started using PHP.

I don't see, how this question is more opinion based than others.

The POSIX specification for bc says the following (with my emphasis added):

Internal computations shall be conducted as if in decimal, regardless of the input and output bases, to the specified number of decimal digits. When an exact result is not achieved (for example, scale=0; 3.2/1), the result shall be truncated.

There is no rationale for this particular behaviour in the current POSIX standard, presumably because the standard is prescribing the behaviour of the existing implementations of the bc utility.  The bc utility that you are using implements this, which is the same truncating behaviour described in "BC - An Arbitrary Precision Desk-Calculator Language" from 1991 (link goes the to the Roff source of the document in the Github repository of OpenBSD):

Division of integers produces an
integer result truncated toward zero.


All of the internal operations are actually carried out in terms
of integers, with digits being discarded when necessary.
In every case where digits are discarded, truncation and
not rounding is performed.

The original author of bc, Lorinda Cherry, is unfortunately no longer with us.  She implemented bc in 1975 for V6 as a frontend to the dc postfix calculator.  POSIX does not standardise the dc utility.
The bc language allows for writing your own functions (which is another reason for not having a rounding functionality built-in), and a naive function r(x) that rounds x to a number of decimal places given by the current value of scale might look like this:
define r(x) {
        auto a,b

        a = obase^scale

        if (x >= 0) b = (x*a + 0.5)/a
        if (x <  0) b = (x*a - 0.5)/a

        return b
}

